# How to use ready-made ML model in Python (sklearn) when all the logic is implemented in another language?

Tags: machine-learning, deployment, scikit-learn, pickle

I have a model. This is an `LGBMClassifier` with `sklearn`. With `pickle`, I saved the model in `.sav` format. 
This is a trading model that will be used to trade US stocks.

Now the task is to use the model for real trading. We want to implement the code on `.net`. It means that the model was created in `Python`, but all code except the model itself will be implemented in another language.

I want to learn how to use the ready-made Python model in production when all the logic except the model itself will be implemented in another language. Can this be done?

I have never solved deployment issues. I will be grateful for any information on this subject. I want to understand in which direction should I move to make the model deployment according to the requirements above.

If there are any other ways to resolve this issue or the described approach does not make sense, I also will be grateful for the comments.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

One way to do this is

1. First put the model dump on [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) [a storage service to store files which can be accessed online easily]
2. Write logic for loading model and predicting on [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) [ a serverless service to write small utilities which can be called from anywhere through [API gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) ], put the AWS lambda behing API Gateway(aws) for accessing it with an API.
3. Call the api from your .net code and get results.

Above answer uses aws ecosystem, you can use others but the process will be same.